# Typescript interface for varying length of object properties depending on a number

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types, interface

[image]

Hi guys, basically i need an interface for Input which has the paddings property expanding depending on the number of column-state. If column is equal to one, paddings should be:

```
{
['pL-0']: string,
['pR-0']: string,
}
```

standing for padding-left and padding-right of column 0.
Can you give me the right interface for paddings?

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)  Without code I can easily copy and paste this isn't a useful [mre].

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hey! Sorry, won't do anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface for padding using the template literals and mixing the possible outcomes of a defined direction type and number.

Such definition could look like:

```
type PaddingDirection = 'L' | 'R'

type Padding = Record<`p${PaddingDirection}-${number}`, string>;

// With open number value
const customPadding: Padding = {
    'pL-2': '1px',
    'pR-20000': '2px',
    'pT-2': '2px' // error: the T direction is not defined
};
```

If you want to be more restrictive, you could even add restrictions on the number values that can go into your definition, like this:

```
type PaddingDirection = 'L' | 'R'
type PaddingValues = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;

type PaddingRestrictedValues = Record<`p${PaddingDirection}-${PaddingValues}`, string>;

// With restricted values
const customPadding: PaddingRestrictedValues = {
    'pL-2': '1px',
    'pL-5': '1px', // error: 5 is not a valid number
};
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgEwQSwHYHMAiyBOEDGwyA9qlALxQDkAMlVAD7UBKVAUKJLIihgGpwANgFcIAZwpQAjIygAmWQGZZAFgDcbDuGjwkadJOYFiOBAB4ABmAAkAb128suAkVIBfALR3UwgLYAjCBw3CwAaKDFgHH0APg1OHR59I0jowggEARFxQ2NTSxt7JIxsPEISVE87B30s0TEQ8NTYjTYAejaoAHVkYAALKGJIMh8AoKgANyFRNnxSSKh8YUjiXxqMAC5uPQxJWzYoQ%20owGg85Ki2qKTAADypQg6OqMGYzgAYPt4vqOVv7x8OzwAKmdvlRfncoB0oEEcCY2G5WtCev0oHhmukEJNpuJZvNgItlsBVut0FtSSkoshMXUcpR9kdjqdzpdrncHoznqcAKxgtn3KGdWEmLbcqDICSoYgEuDYwTILGjQI4BEaIA)